# Set custom class name to storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, oop

I am trying set custom class name to storyboard programmatically in iOS.

I have storyboard with viewcontroller `MyFirstViewController` and set class name as `MyFirstViewController`

Now I create another viewcontroller `SecondViewController` which extends `MyFirstViewController`

```
 SecondViewController *vcsecond = (SecondViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyFirstViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcsecond animated:YES];
```

When I run this app my SecondViewController `viewDidLoad` method not call, it calls `MyFirstViewController` viewDidLoad method.

I get `vcsecond` as object of `MyFirstViewController`.

Please help me how to open `SecondViewController` using `MyFirstViewController` XIB.

I only want to inherit all the functionality of `MyFirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` and also override some method's here and execute some new code in overrided method with additional functionality.

Design of the both viewcontroller is same only add some new functionality using overriding method's.

[image: Please refer this]

In above screen TabSearchForDocViewController is my MyFirstViewController controller.

So my actual question is----------

I have comman storyboard page for two view controller. My SecondViewController is extends MyFirstViewController. Now I want to open my SecondViewController using comman storyboard page. Is it possible to set class name programmatically?

Comment: check your identifier name is correct "MyFirstViewController"?

Comment: yes I checked many time's that is correct but when I push to SecondViewController using above code it's push to the MyFirstViewController class

Comment: `SecondViewController *vcsecond = (SecondViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyFirstViewController"];` check this line again or clean the project and run again, please show me your storyboard page.

Comment: Yes this is all right but when i print vcsecond object it returns me object of MyFirstViewController class, SecondViewController is a child class of MyFirstViewController

Comment: Please show me your storyboard page.

Comment: show me your storyboard page of SecondViewController not MyFirstViewController.

Comment: There no storyboard page for SecondViewController I want to use the same story board page only thing is that my SecondViewController is extends MyFirstViewController and inherits all functionality in SecondViewController. Is this possible? Only want to change custom class name programatically...

Comment: ok, `nice concept`. As per inheritance rule it is possible but i am not doing this in my any project.so best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will always return an instance of the class specified in the corresponding scene in the storyboard - you cannot override this at run time.

I would suggest that you create a 'thin' object which is the class that you specify in the storyboard scene.  You can then create other object classes (using inheritance) that implement the view controller functionality using a delegation pattern.  You can then instantiate the appropriate delegate instance at run time.

Comment: Can you please make me understand using one simple example because I am getting your point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that his will be feasible as your identifier "MyFirstViewController" holds the reference to the class MyFirstViewController and always loads the header files for this class. 
So I don't think that vcsecond would load for you this way.

Comment: No but according to inheritance we can extends all the property of parent in to child. Is this possible using same storyboard page?. I only want to override all property to child and do different execution on different scenario.